# How to copy command string in the ex mode into clipboard?

Tags: vim, copy, mode, ex

How to copy command string in the ex mode into clipboard?

[image]

Comment: Press Shift and select it with mouse, then copy it in terminal menu

Comment: `<C-f>` opens the command-line window where you can yank to the clipboard with `"+yy` or `"*yy`.

Comment: @romainl: Good answer, you should post it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can turn the *command-line mode* into a full Vim buffer named the **command-line window** by pressing `<C-f>` after entering in *command-line mode* with `:`, or enter into it directly via `q:`. There, you can yank as usual; e.g. via `"+yy` or `:yank +<CR>`. (This is also great for other complex edits!)

The last command-line is in register `:`; `:let @+ = @:<CR>` will copy that to the clipboard.

The least Vim-like approach would be selecting with the mouse; on Linux, the text is then in the X primary selection; on Windows, you can then use *Edit > Copy* to put it in the clipboard.

Comment: Are you sure that `<C-f>` does the work you mentioned? If I recall properly, this is for next page.

Comment: @aturegano In Vim, everything depends on the active mode. `<C-f>` is _next page_ in normal mode, but in command-line mode opens the command-line window.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the line to be copied; be in Command mode, *not* Input mode.

Create a "macro" by copying the line into a named buffer.   I like to use `m` for macro:

`"m`

Yank the line into the buffer you just named:

`yy`

Now (still in Command mode) you can "run" the buffer as a "macro" using the standard `@` to address the named buffer:

`@m`

If you run it and there is a mistake, simply press `u` to "undo" and correct the line

`"myy` can become muscle-memory after a short time.

**~ A more detailed example ~**

Make some data just by copying and pasting these commands.

No need to type them:

```
$ printf "
TRUE(1)                           TRUE(1)

N\bNA\bAM\bME\bE
  t\btr\bru\bue\be - return true value

S\bSY\bYN\bNO\bOP\bPS\bSI\bIS\bS
  t\btr\bru\bue\be
" > zap



$ cat <<'EOF' >> zap
This part could just all be typed manually
otherwise append the " before copying into buffer
:%!sed "s/.$(printf '\b')//g
EOF
```

Open the file.  It will likely look pretty funky:

`$ vi zap`

Go to the end of the buffer `G`

Next, go into Input Mode, `o` and enter your "macro" on an empty line, exactly as if you were typing it in Command Mode, including the leading colon to make it easy to spot.

`:%!sed "s/.$(printf '\b')//g"`

We already added most of the line to save you the trouble.  Add the closing double-quote at the end with `<shift+a>`

Always press `<esc>` to exit Input mode when you are done making edits.

Yank the whole line (with "Y" or "yy") into a named buffer.  Again, we are going to simply use the name "m" for macro to make it easy to remember.

You can have multiple "macros" this way with different letter-names, but you need to remember them.

`"myy`

Once you are ready, use Command Mode to run the "macro", via @ and the buffer name.

`@m`

If done correctly, the text should instantly become "un-borked".

Obviously this is a short "macro", but it gives you the idea.
The biggest advantage to doing it this way is that it is "proper" `ex` and `vi` usage as defined by POSIX so it should work without *vim*.

If you want to copy text into the *OS-level* clipboard, then just pipe it to `xsel`, `xclip`, `pbcopy` or the like in a similar manner.